# PHP/MYSQL Query: Get line above and below result!

Tags: php, mysql, view

I somehow need a way for the following:

User is located at some blog page Now I want to give him the ability to move either:

To the next more popular page OR to the next less popular page. Means, something like this:

```
[PAGE 5] | [PAGE 3 (User is here)] | [PAGE 2]
```

(Where Page 1 = most popular, Page 3 = least popular). My MySQL Table looks like this:

```
[ID] [VIEWS]
[1] [1000]
[2] [2560]
[3] [3200]
[4] [200]
[5] [4000]
```

My problem is the specific query. The only given variable is the ID: 2 in this case. Maybe you can help me out. Just tell me if you need further informations.
(I only need the two neighbours. Page 4 etc. would not be needed.)

Edit: @Trevor No, sorry I cant. I changed the example so its more clearly.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just query for ID=1 or ID=3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE**: As worked out in the various comments, [@mellamokb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147518/php-mysql-query-get-line-above-and-below-result/5147658#5147658) is better than mine. I would delete this answer but am unable to since it was accepted.

```
/* Next Page */
SELECT ID
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE VIEWS <= (SELECT VIEWS FROM YourTable WHERE ID = $CurrentPageId)
        AND ID < $CurrentPageId
    ORDER BY VIEWS DESC, ID DESC LIMIT 1

/* Previous Page */
SELECT ID
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE VIEWS >= (SELECT VIEWS FROM YourTable WHERE ID = $CurrentPageId)
        AND ID > $CurrentPageId
    ORDER BY VIEWS, ID LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Now just to add a sprinkle of `INNER` or `LEFT JOINS` and you're sorted.

Comment: I think you got previous and next page backwards according to OP's specs.  Also, what happens if two or more pages have same # of views?  Then they will be skipped.

Comment: @mellamokb, @razzed: Thanks. Adjusted for ties.

Comment: And, once again a pedantry.  See my answer.  This is what I had first before I realized it would not work if we go from `id=5, views=4000` to `id=4, views=5000` because views is larger, but id is smaller.  You only want the case `ID < $CurrentPageId` when `VIEWS` is = between multiple entries.

Comment: @mellamokb: You are correct. I'll +1 your answer because if I fiddle with mine any more, it will just end up looking like yours.

Answer (score 1):

For previous page:

```
  select ID as PreviousId
    from PageViews
   where Views > (select Views From PageViews Where ID = @Id)
      or (
             Views = (select Views From PageViews Where ID = @Id)
             and ID > @id
         )
order by Views ASC, ID DESC
   limit 1
```

For next page:

```
  select ID as PreviousId
    from PageViews
   where Views < (select Views From PageViews Where ID = @Id)
      or (
             Views = (select Views From PageViews Where ID = @Id)
             and ID < @id
         )
order by Views DESC, ID DESC
   limit 1
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want ASCending ORDER on the first query?

Comment: @Joe:  Yep. Thanks! Lol, between the two of us we oughta get a good answer!

Comment: Crowdsourcing at its best! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Three queries:

```
SELECT @MyID:=ID,@MyViews:=Views FROM Table WHERE ID=2;
```

Using local "Views":

```
SELECT ID,Views FROM Table WHERE Views <= @MyViews AND ID != @MyID ORDER BY Views DESC LIMIT 1;
SELECT ID,Views FROM Table WHERE Views >= @MyViews AND ID != @MyID ORDER BY Views ASC LIMIT 1;
```

And, make sure you have an index on Views.

Comment: His example above was edited mid-stream and was confusing because his Page 1, Page 2, Page 3 were ordered incorrectly, BY ID. He edited mid-stream, and I edited to correct. I'll stick with my sheesh.

Comment: @razzed: With the ID != comparision, you could potentially end up in an infinite loop bouncing back and forth between ID=4, Views=100 and ID=5, Views=100. You'd want to test < or > as in [@mellamokb's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147518/php-mysql-query-get-line-above-and-below-result/5147658#5147658)

Answer (score 0):

or

```
    /* Previous Page */
SELECT ID
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE VIEWS < $CurrentPageViews 
    ORDER BY VIEWS DESC LIMIT 1

/* Next Page */
SELECT ID
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE VIEWS > $CurrentPageViews
    ORDER BY VIEWS LIMIT 1
```